# Yeoman angular generator: development server works, but after build an infi-digest error is thrown

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

the code that causes the issue:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('metaCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch(function (){ return $(document).height() }, function(val){
            $scope.config = {minHeight: val}
        });
  });
```

somehow he value of config.minHeight raises on each invocation of the $watcher function.

Already spent 4 hours trying to debug this.

Any help is much appreciated.

What is different between grunt development sever and serving from the dist folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide string literals for dependency injection. This is because upon minification, your variable names will  be broken down and your `$scope` will be gone. It works in development server, because in development server JS files aren't minified. But in distribution, they are.

```
angular.module('myApp')
//inject your $scope using inline annotation so that it doesn't break upon minification.
 .controller('metaCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(function (){ return $(document).height() }, function(val){
        $scope.config = {minHeight: val}
    });
}]);
```